# Types conforming to multiple protocols in swift

Tags: swift

I have an Objective-C variable that conforms to multiple protocols.

```
id <NSObject, NSCopying, NSCoding> identityToken;
```

How would I represent this type in Swift?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

This should work:

```
var identityToken: NSObjectProtocol & NSCopying & NSCoding
```

Note you have to use NSObjectProtocol instead of NSObject in swift.

**Here are some additional examples:**

Array of objects conforming to multiple protocols:

```
var array: [NSObjectProtocol & NSCopying & NSCoding]
```

Function with a parameter that conforms to multiple protocols:

```
func foo(param: NSObjectProtocol & NSCopying & NSCoding) {

}
```

For Swift version before 3.1, use:

```
var identityToken: (NSObjectProtocol, NSCopying, NSCoding)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why `NSObjectProtocol` must be used?

Comment: @aleclarson In objective-c there is an NSObject class and protocol. Swift uses NSObject and NSObjectProtocol to differentiate between the two.

Comment: Oh nevermind. I completely misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: Very cool. Wasn't aware of this (somewhat awkward) syntax. However, how can you do this with an explicit class as well, for example in obj-c: `MyClass<ProtcolOne, ProtocolTwo>`?

Comment: @connor what if you would like to specify the type as well (like a table view cell conforming to a protocol)? Is this possible or must we rely on Swifts implicit typing?

Comment: @DanielGalasko I don't believe you can. You may be able to use a class stub instead? Something like `class Cell: UITableViewCell, NSObjectProtocol {}`

Comment: @connor That stub would have compiler warnings since that class doesn't actually conform to those protocols?

Comment: Oh right. I saw your new question, hopefully it gets an answer

Comment: @devios You may replace MyClass<ProtocolOne, ProtocolTwo> by using generics: func foo<T: MyClass where T: protocol<ProtocolOne, ProtocolTwo>>(params: T)

Comment: @Oscar thanks for the helpful tip. how can one declare MyClass<ProtocolOne, ProtocolTwo>  as a variable?

Comment: @ILiΛƧKΛЯiM Try using generics on the class to specify that generic type constraint. I.e. `class MyClass <T: MyClass where T: protocol<ProtocolOne, ProtocolTwo>> { let x: T; func test(y: T) { x = y } }`

Comment: `typealias MyCombindedProtocol = protocol<NSObjectProtocol, NSCopying, NSCoding>`

`var myProtocols = [MyCombindedProtocol]()`

`func foo(param: MyCombindedProtocol) { }`

You may want to use a typealias to make it look a bit prettier :)

Comment: For those curious, in Swift 3, the syntax for multiple protocol conformance is now `ProtoA & ProtoB`, apparently

Answer (score 12):

Swift 3

```
var idToken: NSObjectProtocol & NSCopying & NSCoding

func foo(_ delegateAndDataSource: UICollectionViewDelegate & UICollectionViewDataSource) { ... }
```

Answer (score 8):

Seems like you could also type-alias the composite protocols, which may come in handy if you plan on using the same combination of protocol multiple times.

```
typealias IDToken = NSObjectProtocol & NSCopying & NSCoding
```

Same examples as given in the accepted answer, using a type-alias:

```
var idToken: IDToken

var array: [IDToken] = []

func foo(param: IDToken) { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

The above answer from conner is correct, however you often should implement a separate protocol that itself inherits from the other protocols, and allows you more flexibility, should you want to add additional protocol methods later or change the top level protocols.

```
internal protocol MyOtherProtocol : NSObjectProtocol, NSCopying, NSCoding {
    func someOtherNecessaryMethod()
}
```

Then utilized:

```
var identityToken : MyOtherProtocol
```

Answer (score 0):

For generics this works as well:

```
func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate<D: UICollectionViewDataSource & UICollectionViewDelegate>
```