# Swift property conforming with multiple protocols

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I have custom UIView (`CustomView`) conforming to two different protocols

```
protocol ResizableDelegate: class {
    func view(view:UIView, didChangeHeight difference:CGFloat)
}
protocol Resizable: class {
    var delegate:ResizableDelegate? { set get }
}


protocol TappableDelegate: class {
    func viewDidTap(view:UIView)
}
protocol Tappable {
    var delegate:TappableDelegate? { set get }
}
```

And I need to have a property in my `CustomView` class named `delegate` and conforming to these two protocols at the same time. I read [Types conforming to multiple protocols in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027380/types-conforming-to-multiple-protocols-in-swift) but that is not solving my problem.

I created this protocol

```
protocol CustomViewDelegate: ResizableDelegate, TappableDelegate {}
```

And then make my `CustomView`

```
class CustomView : UIView, Resizable, Tappable {
    var delegate:CustomViewDelegate?
}
```

But that is causing me to get a message

```
Type 'CustomView' does not conform to protocol 'Resizable'
```

I don't want to have:

```
class CustomView : UIView, Resizable, Tappable {
   var resizableDelegate:ResizableDelegate?
   var TappableDelegate:TappableDelegate?
}
```

Is there any way two have only one delegate property that conforms to these two protocols at the same time? Im using swift 2.0, Xcode 7.

Comment: What do you mean by "that is not solving my problem" regarding the "Types conforming to multiple protocols" answer. That looks like exactly the solution to your problem as stated.

Comment: That my class needs to conform to `Resizable` and  `Tappable` at the same time, and both protocols have a property called `delegate` that should conform to different protocols.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you don't really need to declare `Resizable` and `Tappable` protocols. All you need is to delegate from your custom view to some other object, which confirms to both `ResizableDelegate` and `TappableDelegate`, right? If so, this should work for you:

```
protocol ResizableDelegate: class {
    func view(view:UIView, didChangeHeight difference:CGFloat)
}

protocol TappableDelegate: class {
    func viewDidTap(view:UIView)
}

class CustomView : UIView {
    var delegate: (ResizableDelegate, TappableDelegate)?

}
```

Comment: That only works if I remove the delegate properties from `Resizable` and `Tappable`

Comment: @fbernaly Are you sure you really need to know that some object has delegates? It is not exactly how delegation works. Let me know if the updated answer works for you.

Comment: that is what I did, I had to remove `Resizable` and `Tappable` from `CustomView`, and it is working. But let me explain why I wanted `CustomView` to conform to `Resizable` and `Tappable`: I have some views that should be either `Resizable` and/or `Tappable`, so, the superview needs to know that in order to be the delegate for that custom view.

Comment: So, what I thought of was: "Im your superview, if you are resizable Im your delegate, if you are tappable Im your delegate, else nothing", but because now `CustomView` and the other custom views (let's say `CustomView2`) are not `Resizable` neither `Tappable` I need to do: "Im your superview, if you are `CustomView` I'm your delegate, if you are `CustomView2` I'm your delegate, if you are `CustomView3` I'm your delegate... and so on"... I will have the same amount of if-statement as the classes with those delegates, in the former cases just 2 if-statements

Answer (score 0):

Although you can leave things as is, I would strongly recommend changing the required properties to "tappableDelegate" and "resizableDelegate" thus having two separate properties in your View subclass.

Your specific use case may require adherence to both, but having the same naming means you would not be able to have different delegates.