# how to declare a member with multiple protocols in swift?

Tags: swift, swift3

in Obj-C you can do this:

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject <ProtocolA, ProtocolB>
@end

@interface YourClass: NSObject
@property(nonatomic) id<ProtocolA, ProtocolB> someDelegate;
@end
```

so you can set an object of MyClass as the someDelegate of object of YourClass.

But how can I do this in swift? You can't declare something like:

```
var delegate: ProtocolA, ProtocolB
```

Thanks.

I know there's a solution of

```
protocol ProtocolC: ProtocolA, ProtocolB {}
```

that can work on both languages. But this is not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: see http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/ & see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027380/types-conforming-to-multiple-protocols-in-swift

Comment: for your future questions, always link questions you saw before and why they didn't answer your question...

Comment: thanks Honey, can you make this an answer so I can honor it?