# How to use 'any' with multiple protocol types?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, any

I had the following:

```
protocol MyProtocol: CustomStringConvertible, CaseIterable {
    ...
}

...

var objects: [any MyProtocol]
```

Now I want to get rid of `MyProtocol`.

Probably a silly question, but how do I then define my `objects` property?  This:

```
var objects: [any CustomStringConvertible, CaseIterable]
```

of course doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[any CustomStringConvertible & CaseIterable]`

Comment: Just found that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24027473/1971013 as well.  My question is more like a duplicate.

Comment: Good catch. Marked so folks can find it.